# Error: "message":"PermissionDenied","type":"DomainError" after user tried to log in

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, openid-connect, openid, openid-provider

Please, could you give me some clue or indication where to go?
I have checked the settings several times from our side, we are the IDP, and I am not able to detect the reason for this error.

**The flow is:**

User reaches the RP website => Click on Log In => A new window opens so that the user can log in to the IDP => The user enters their credentials and clicks on Log In => The window displays the following error:

> "message":"PermissionDenied","type":"DomainError"

Many Thanks

Comment: Could you please share more details about the Website/framework of the application.

Comment: @Harshitha IDP is just configure in Azure AD as WebApp using OpenID. RP is using .Net. Many Thanks.

Comment: What is the framework you are using.Could you please share your `configuration` and source files.

Comment: @Harshitha. The framework is 4.7.1. I am not sure about if we can share these files. Besides, I think RP is using Azure AD to configure all stuff from their side. I think, could be some problem in the configuration itself. Don´t ring a bell to you these message errors?

Comment: You can share by Masking your values.

Comment: @Harshitha. I need to raise a petition to my manager and then she will raise another petition to the RP. I would discard this option. I hope, you can give me any hint or clue coming from the error message. Something from where I can start to check, just because I am quite lost at this point. Many Thanks

Comment: Do you have `app.authentication()` and `app.authorization()` in your code?

Comment: @Harshitha. We are the IDP. We just configure our endpoint and so on by Azure AD. For the error provided, it looks like RP is already doing the HTTP request but at some point in the configuration, probably, by our side or by their side, there are some errors. We need to know what possible things are happening. Many Thanks